# TabStops definitions does not work in PdfSharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am fighting with tab stops in PdfSharp but none I have tried worked.

I have finally this code:

```
Paragraph para = row.Cells[0].AddParagraph();
para.AddText(att.EventDate.ToString("ddd").Substring(0, 2).ToUpper());
para.Format.TabStops.ClearAll();
para.Format.TabStops.AddTabStop("0.3mm");
para.AddTab();
para.AddText(att.EventDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

The calling to AddTab adds a normal tab, not the one I have defined.

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Jaime

EDIT:

what I need to achieve is to format a date with the 2 letters day name, for example, "MO dd/mm/yyyy". I need to use tabstops because I need all dates to be aligned, considering that day names will vary in width depending on the letters. 3 mm is good enough to achieve this.

Comment: 0.3mm is awfuuly small, imo. sure about that?

Comment: 3mm is still very small. If the text before the tab is longer than 3mm, the text after the tab will probably move to the next default position. Tab stops work well with MigraDoc.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind... I have placed 2 column tables inside the date cells. That way I could align perfectly the way I want.

Cheers
Jaime